# Could not load file or assembly in COM visible class library C#

Tags: c#, .net

I've created a class library project, and installed Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package. This operation added an app.config file, which contains:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Then I've made the class library COM visible:

[image: Made library COM visible]

When I tried to use my class library in another C# WinForms project, I was getting error:

> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

until I've added the same app.config lines in the WinForms project.

Now I'm trying to use my assembly (referenced via COM) in Microsoft Word VBA developer, and I'm getting the same error, but I can't make an app.config file for Microsoft Word, can I? Is there any way, how this issue can be solved?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your referenced assembly is missing the Json.dll in your new project. To test this you can manual add the json.dll to the output folder of your new project.

Comment: Have you tried using a publisher policy? That should apply the redirect to "all application" trying to use older versions. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz32563a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, I haven't. I'll try and let you know about the results. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is a standard DLL Hell problem you'll have when you make a .NET assembly [ComVisible].  The CLR uses its normal way to look for dependent assemblies, those rules do not change in COM.  It first looks in the GAC, it next looks in directory where the EXE is located.  It does **not** look in the directory where your [ComVisible] assembly is located.  Otherwise something that is easy to see with Fuslogvw.exe, be sure to practice it.

There are multiple solutions to this problem, none are ideal so you'll have to pick the one that suits you best yourself.  First thing you should *strongly* pursue is to get rid of the .config file.  The `<bindingRedirect>` is always generated but is often unnecessary.  It is only truly required when you reference multiple Nuget packages and they disagree about what version of Newtonsoft.Json.dll to use.  If that's a problem then only deployment into the Office folder is practical, see the last bullet.

- Deploy everything to the GAC.  This is normally the ideal solution for COM, it has a strong DLL Hell problem in general because registration is machine-wide.  That makes deploying updates dangerous, you might fix a problem in one program but break another.  Disadvantage is the install requirement.  And the questionable practice of putting Newtonsoft.Json.dll in the GAC, an assembly that has a pretty opaque versioning history and is used by many other programs.  Nonzero odds you'll break another app that uses it since it now loads the copy in the GAC instead of its local copy.  The FUD is strong enough to avoid this.
- Use ILMerge so you'll only have a single DLL.  Does not always work, it can't handle mixed-mode assemblies and cannot handle binding redirects.  Try it and you'll quickly find out.  Other than that, the only disadvantage is the extra build step.
- Subscribe the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve event and help the CLR to locate the dependency.  Practical when you expose a limited number of classes or if only a few have a dependency.  Best to subscribe the event in the static constructor of the class so it happens as early as possible.  Be sure to do it only once.  Be sure to test the Release build without a debugger, the jitter might require the dependency before any code starts running.
- Copy the dependencies into the Office install folder.  That's where the CLR will look after it checked the GAC.  If you need the bindingRedirect then the config file needs to be copied there as well, renamed to, say, Excel.exe.config to match the Office program name.  Disadvantage is an admin that doesn't like you messing with that folder.  And the problem of *two* programs doing this, the second overwriting your DLL or .config file, perhaps years after you finished your project.  Not your problem, you'll get an ugly phone call anyway.